# How to restrict Subscriber to one custom post type and restraint them from editing other post

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, custom-post-type, subscriber

Hi I'm trying to make a custom section for a wordpress site and I need to give some access to my subscriber.

I created a custom post type (boat). What I need to do is :

1 - Grant access to any subcriber to my custom post type.

2 - Grant permission to any subscribers to publish / edit / delete / upload file only in their own post (+ permission to assign their post to one of the already created taxonomy I made)

3 - Restrict them from viewing / editing other subscribers post

4 - I don't want the subscriber to see something else than their profile and the custom post type section

I tried to use role scoper, wp-Members and Capability Manager but none of them seem to do exactly what I want. If you know how to do it I'd really appreciate

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did, instead of granting subscriber all these permission, I upgraded all my subscribers to contributor.

I changed the capability of my custom post type to:

```
$args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'boat' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'capabilities'       => array(
                                'publish_posts'       => 'edit_posts',//contributor can edit
                                'edit_others_posts'   => 'update_core',//administrator can see other
                                'delete_posts'        => 'update_core',//administrator can see other
                                'delete_others_posts' => 'update_core',//administrator can see other
                                'read_private_posts'  => 'update_core',//administrator can see other
                                'edit_post'           => 'edit_posts',//contributor can edit
                                'delete_post'         => 'update_core',//administrator can see other
                                'read_post'           => 'edit_posts',//contributor can edit
                                ),
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title','revision' )
);

register_post_type("boat", $args);
```

Then I added some custom function I found at different webpage :

This one hide the menu I dont want the contributor to see

source : [source 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142517/remove-ability-to-access-certain-admin-menus)
and : [source 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/possible-to-hide-custom-post-type-ui-menu-from-specific-user-roles)

```
function remove_menus(){

  $author = wp_get_current_user();
  if(isset($author->roles[0])){ 
     $current_role = $author->roles[0];
  }else{
     $current_role = 'no_role';
  }

  if($current_role == 'contributor'){  
     remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
     remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
     remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
     remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );               //Comments
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=my_other_custom_post_type_I_want_to_hide' );
  }

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Then I restricted contributor from seings other post with :
from : [source 3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81772/contributor-disable-seeing-others-posts)

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'posts_for_current_contributor' );
function posts_for_current_contributor() {
    global $user_ID;

    if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_GET['author'] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'author', $user_ID ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I allowed contributor to upload file with :
from [source 4](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77613/allow-contributor-role-to-upload-images-and-not-edit-already-published-articles)

```
add_action('admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads');

function allow_contributor_uploads() {
    $contributor = get_role('contributor');
    $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

Since I got a bunch of custom field in my custom post type I made with [ACF (Advance custom field)](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) I restricted the media upload to only local post so my contributor cant use media from other people.

I hope this will help someone! :)